# Not able to Create/Delete table

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I made the mistake of deleting a table via object explorer. I tried to create a table with the same name and I get the error that an object with that name already exists. I have the server role system admin

I have tried the following commands.

```
DROP TABLE 'Test'
```

Result:

> Can not drop table because it doesnt exist or you do not have permission.

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES order by 3
```

Result:

> There are no result with Table name Test

```
select * from sys.objects where name = 'Test'
```

Result:

Blank Table

When I type DROP TABLE intellisense shows a table with the name Test. It seems like its a permission issue, but since I have Server Role as sysadmin I am not sure how that can be.

I am not sure if this matters but I imported this db from a staging server.

Comment: Are you sure it's a *table* with the name `Test` and not a database that IntelliSense shows you?

Comment: Is this SSMS intellisense, or a third party (e.g. Redgate) - I can't seem to get any intellisense for `DROP TABLE` in SSMS. Also, like Andriy, I suspect it's some other object type - a schema maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are in the correct and same database context for all operations

To find which database the table exists in:

```
EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'USE ? SELECT DB_NAME() FROM sys.objects WHERE name = ''Test'' '
```

Comment: Alternatively: `EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachdb 'IF OBJECT_ID(''?..Customer'') IS NOT NULL PRINT ''?'''` (but that does not take schemas into account).

Comment: @Andriy M: I think OP would be happy finding anything called 'test' just now :-)

Answer (score 0):

When use SysObjects use the xType Column:

```
select * from sys.objects where name = 'Test' and xType = 'U'
```

Maybe there is an object with the same name, using xtype = 'U' we can know if there is a User Table.